# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock is not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to register a script block from code behind using the below code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "MethodUpdate", "PopulateData();", True)
```

but its not working. Am getting the error like PopulateData is undefined

Comment: You have to define `PopulateData()` in front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code which should work fine

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SomeUniqueName", ";$(function() { PopulateData(); })", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your code in head section.

```
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        PopulateData(alert('Hi'));
    });
</script>
</head>
```

and you can call from code behind.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "MethodUpdate", "PopulateData();", True)
```